# isset value always returns 1

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, isset

I am a newbie when it comes to PHP. I am trying to make a login and logout webpage. Now, I have created a page which would add records. MY code always returns 1 from the form that i built, irrespective of the value in the form.
My code-

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $alpha = isset($_GET["username"]);
    $beta = isset($_GET["password"]);
    $gama = isset($_GET["hobby"]);
    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root" ,"","member");

    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO data (username,password,hobby)
        VALUES ($alpha, $beta, $gama)";

    if ($conn->query($sql)=== TRUE) {
        echo $alpha."Your record is added into our database ";
    } else {
        echo $sql.$conn->error;
    }                                          
?>
```

And this is my form:

```
<form action="add.php">
  <table> 
    <tr>
        <td>Username :</td>  <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td>Password :</td>   <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hobbies:</td>   <td><textarea name="hobby" id="hobby" cols="22" rows="7"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>    </td><td><input type="submit" name="submit"></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: checkout [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) , and your code is vulnerable to sql injections;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because `isset()` returns a boolean value.

If you want to directly print the `username` field you can just:

```
if(isset($_GET["username"])) { 
    echo $_GET["username"];
}
```

So you should understand that the variables `$alpha`, `$beta`, `$gamma` do not hold the actual string you expect but a boolean value

See more at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: This is correct. Also note that it is an extremely dangerous practice to try and insert user data by direct query like that. Please search on the topics of sql injection attacks and PDO

Comment: You are absolutely correct. But the question is about the isset behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Its because the isset() function checks whether the key in an array is set or not it doesn't checks whether the value is set or not. In your case; when you post your form to the action the POST array contains all the keys hence isset returning 1 as usual. I think you need to have a look at php empty() function. Or you might want to use the mixture of isset() and empty().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: OP will have the same issue because they are using the Boolean result as the data to insert.